# SetClip painting into ScrollBar

Tags: java, clipping

I'm using a Panel into JScrollPane. In the Panel's paintComponent method I'm painting Polygons. [image: Example of the polygons painted]
The method is working fine, but if I want to use the Polygon as clipping region the content (in the example the line) is drawn into the scrollbar of the JScrollPane. I also tried a repaint of the ScrollPane after drawing the polygons - no effect

```
    Shape s=g2.getClip();

    g2.setClip(poly);
    g2.drawLine(poly.xpoints[0], poly.ypoints[0], poly.xpoints[0]+200, poly.ypoints[0]+200);
    g2.setClip(s);
```

Comment: Looks like your Panel's clip is larger than what is given to  g2.
Have you tried comparing the paint component bounds with clipping bounds? using,
g2.getClipBounds()

Comment: Yes it's larger. But nevertheless it should not paint on the upper graphics.

Comment: Post values you've given to the poly, which you are passing to the setClip

Comment: The Polygons are passed for each Hexagon that is painted (see image). So of course there are polygons outside the visible area. But if no clipping is activated the scrollbars are not hit.

Comment: Try, one of this, should work (import java.awt.Rectangle;)
-----
   ``Rectangle r = g2.getClipBounds();
    g2.drawLine(poly.xpoints[0],poly.ypoints[0],r.width, r.height);``
-------    
    ``Rectangle r = g2.getClipBounds();
    g2.drawLine(poly.xpoints[0],poly.ypoints[0],r.width+200, r.height200);``

Comment: The line is just an example. I want to constrain the drawing area to the hexagon so I can subclass and draw just in the constrained area